# YOLO v4 bounding box and labels sorting

Tags: python, opencv, yolov4

I have trained YOLO on license plate character recognition dataset, then I have implemented using OpenCV. Now, when I try to recognize the characters, detection is good, but the Labels are shuffled. I don't know how to sort the bounding box or labels from left to right and from top to bottom.
In this picture, character detection accuracy is good, but when I print the Labels, their order is changed. Like:
6LJE195.
How Can I sort the bounding boxes or labels.
[2 row License plate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOnle.jpg)
[1 row license plate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbABJ.jpg)